# reactにおけるクラスコンポーネントと関数コンポーネント間でのthisキーワードの変換

Tags: javascript, reactjs

クラスコンポーネントから関数コンポーネントへ変換する際に、クラスコンポーネントそのものを指す"this"キーワードをどのように関数コンポーネントで記述すればよいか分からず困っております。

下記のようなnotificetion.jsがあったとし、

```
let instance = null;

class Notification {
  constructor() {
    if (!instance) {
      instance = this;
    }
    return instance;
  }

  addObserver = (name, observer, callback) => {
    let obs = observers[name];
    if (!obs) {
      observers[name] = [];
    }
    let obj = { observer: observer, callback: callback };
    observers[name].push(obj);
  };
}
```

これをもともとitemlist.jsにおいて

```
let ntf = new Notification();
class itemList extends Component{
  constructor(props{
    super(props);
    this.state = {itemList:[]}

  })

  componentDidMount(){
　　//この2番目の引数であるthisについて
    ntf.addObserver("List Changed",this,this.onItemListChanged)
  }

  onItemListChanged(newItemList){
    this.setState({itemList:newItemList})
  }
}
```

のような形で使用していたとします。
このitemlist.jsを下記のように変換して使用したいです。

```
let ntf = new Notification();
function WishList(props) {
  const [itemList, setitemList] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    //thisキーワードの扱い
    ntf.addObserver("List Changed",this,this.onItemListChanged)
  });
  
  const onItemListChanged = (newItemList) => {
    setWishList(newItemList);
  };
}
```

このような形でそのまま実行してもエラーとなるため、困っております。どのようにすればクラスから関数へ変えることができるでしょうか。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 質問文のコードから分からなかったのですが、何かしらの理由により`observer`の参照が必要という事でしょうか？それが特に不要であれば、`callback`だけ渡せばいいのかな、と思いました(参考コード: https://jsfiddle.net/4kngd78L/ ,参考記事: [React Hooks and the “Observer” Pattern | by Gerardo Fernández | JavaScript in Plain English](https://javascript.plainenglish.io/react-hooks-and-the-observer-pattern-1e4274f0e5f5))。`observer`の参照が使われる理由によっては何を渡すべきなのか回答が変わる可能性も???

Comment: React公式のサンプルでは`friend.id`と`callback`を渡す実装のObserverパターンが紹介されていますね。[クリーンアップを有する副作用#フックを使った例](https://ja.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#example-using-hooks-1)

Comment: とくにobserverの参照は必要ということではないです。参考コードやリンクなどありがとうございます。

Comment: なるほど。では `name` と `callback` だけ渡すように `Notification` の実装を変えてしまえば `this` を渡す必要もなくなって解決ですね。回答はご自身でも投稿可能ですので、気が向かれたら実際に解決した方法を投稿してみてください。